# How to covert INT_PTR to Structure or Structure pointer in c

Tags: c, dynamic, dll

i am trying to call function from dll in c program . function returns pointer to structure but when i trying to call this function using GetProcAddress function it is returning INT_PTR .

```
HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary("C:\\path-of-dll\library.dll");
  if(!hDll){
}else{
 FARPROC fn = GetProcAddress(hDll,"function-name");
  if(!fn){
    printf("\n Could not find function address");
  }else{
    INT_PTR storingvalue = fn(&chararray1[0],&chararray2[0],&chararray3[0]);
  }
}
```

fn will return pointer to structure. Structure 
{ Pointer to another structure,
  Pointer to another structure
}
Question 
Q1) How can i convert INT_PTR to Structure pointer and fetch data from the same pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

It will require a cast, and it will depend on exactly what the value the function returns actually represents.

If the value is actually a "struct foo *" (which seems likely given your description) then:

```
struct foo * ptr = (struct foo *)storingvalue;
```

regardless, some kind of cast will be needed (as will the return value of GetProcAddress in all but the simplest of cases).

If you only need the result in one expression you could do the following:

```
((struct foo *)storingvalue)->member
```